# .hgignore file is not ignoring the maven target/site directory

Tags: maven, target, hgignore

I've created a basic maven/mercurial setup. I've created a .hgignore in the working directory. I have added the following to the .hgignore file (as per the instructions in https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore

```
/target$
/.DS_Store$
.DS_Store$
```

I had run **hg status** and everything was ignored (as expected)

I ran **mvn site**. Now, when I run the **hg status** command, **everything but** the **site** folder is being ignored in the **target** folder... e.g.

```
~/dev/blah >hg st  

? target/site/css/maven-base.css
? target/site/css/maven-theme.css
? target/site/css/print.css
...
```

nb: as stated earlier, the other files in the target folder (.class, .xml, etc...) **HAVE** been ignored...

The target/site folder has not been added to the repository (as far as I can tell...)

anyone know where I'm going wrong...?

**update**: z3a inspired me to try **^target/*$** and that appears to have done the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ignore the target dir, but not the target/site in your .hgignore put something like this:

```
syntax: regexp
^target/(?!site)
```

Comment: Cheers, but I did actually want to remove the site folder 
...
...
(however, you inspired me to try **^target/*$** and that seems to have done the trick, thanks!!!