# .hgignore 'target' folder with some exceptions

Tags: java, regex, mercurial, hgignore

I use Mercurial and have standard Maven layout for my project with several submodules, e.g.:

```
submodule1/src/main/java/xyz/.../
submodule1/src/main/java/xyz/.../target/Target.java
submodule1/src/test/java/xyz/.../target/TargetTest.java
submodule1/target/classes/xyz/.../target/Target.class
submodule1/target/something_else...
submodule2/...
etc...
```

To exclude all `target` folders from SCM, except when `target` is under `src`, e.g., `submodule1/src/main/java/xyz/.../target/Target.java`, I tried the following `.hgignore`s:

```
syntax: regexp
^(?!(/src/).)/target$
```

(don't match if any folder is named `src`, but match if there is `target` folder)

and

```
syntax: regexp
^[^/]*/(?!(/src/).)*[^/]*/target$
```

(some folders, don't match if any folder is named `src`, then some other folders, then `target` folder).

But both of these `.hgignore`s don't work, the `submodule1/src/main/java/xyz/.../target` folder is still excluded, along with the other `target` folders.

Previously, I solved this with ignoring only the `target` located directly in the submodule folder, e.g.

```
syntax: regexp
^submodule1/target$
```

but there are too many submodules, and this requires editing `.hgignore` each time a submodule is added.

I got the ideas for regexp syntax from [.hgignore file is not ignoring the maven target/site directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202927/hgignore-file-is-not-ignoring-the-maven-target-site-directory) and [hgignore: help ignoring all files but certain ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512058/hgignore-help-ignoring-all-files-but-certain-ones).

P.S. I know that I can `hg add` the files excluded by `.hgignore`, and I've done just that. But this is a temporary measure.

Comment: Side note: I found out why my regexps had no effect. I apparently had `syntax: glob */target/**` somewhere in my `.hgignore`. Without that line they allow everything in the `target` folder anywhere, which is not correct either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way. It identifies just /target/'s that aren't a subdir of /src/

```
 # "^(?=.*/target/)(?!(?:(?!/src/|/target/).)*/src/.*(?<=/)target/)"

 ^                                  # BOS
 (?= .* /target/ )                  # Contains /target/, 
 (?!                                # But, does not contain /src/ .. /target/
      (?:
           (?! /src/ | /target/ )
           . 
      )*
      /src/ .* (?<= / ) target/
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I shortened the regexp some, replacing non-capturing `(?:)` with plain `()`. It's looks _a bit less scary_ that way: `^(?=.*/target/)(?!((?!/src/|/target/).)*/src/.*(?<=/)target/)` :-)